# Dajngo inline formset and errors for required field

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

This is my model:

```
class dateEvent(models.Model):

    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    event = models.ForeignKey('Event', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_date_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
```

My views.py:

```
def event_edit_view(request, id):
    event = get_object_or_404(Event, id=id)
    #MyOtherForm instantiated by event
    DateEventFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Event, dateEvent, extra=5, can_delete=True, fields=('event', 'start_date_time', 'venue', 'link', 'link_description'),
    widgets={
    'venue': s2forms.Select2Widget(),
    'start_date_time': CalendarWidget(),
    form_date_event = DateEventFormSet(request.POST or None, instance=Event.objects.get(id=id), prefix="dateEvent", queryset=dateEvent.objects.filter(event__id=id))

    if request.method == "POST":

        if MyOtherForm.is_valid() and form_date_event.is_valid():

            MyOtherForm.save()
            form_date_event.save()
            return redirect('my-events')

        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError(form_date_event.errors) #?

    context = {
        [other forms...]
        'form_date_event': form_date_event,
        }

    return render(request, "events/template.html", context)
```

And my template.html:

```
<table id="dateEvent">
        <thead>
        <th>Venue</th>
        <th>Date and time</th>
        <th>Link</th>
        <th>Link description</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody id='date_body'>
          {{ form_date_event.management_form }}
          {% for formDate in form_date_event.forms %}

         <tr class="form-row-dateEvent" style='display:table-row;'>
            <td>{{formDate.venue}}<br>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-open="addVenue" onclick="sessionStorage.setItem('venueField', 'id_dateEvent-{{forloop.counter0}}-venue'); document.getElementById('addVenueForm').reset(); document.getElementById('errorVenue').innerText = '';">Add a new venue</a></td>
            <td>{{ formDate.start_date_time}}</td>
            <td>{{formDate.link}} {{formDate.this_composition}}</td>
            <td>{{formDate.id}}{{formDate.link_description}}</td>
         </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Now, how can I enforce the user to fill in both venue and the date? As it is now if a user fills in the venue field and leaves the corresponding date field empty, Django redirects the user to an ugly yellow page

```
ValidationError at /private/event-edit/1150/

['This field is required.']

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    .../event-edit/1150/
Django Version:     3.1
Exception Type:     ValidationError
Exception Value:    

['This field is required.']

Exception Location:     /home/.../.../.../views.py, line 682, in event_edit_view
```

if `DEBUG=TRUE` is set, otherwise an even uglier Error 500. Is there a way that the user would get a nice 'please fill in this field' message in the same row next to the populated venue field, when they hit the 'submit' button?

**PS**

Do I need to declare a custom clear() method, according to which if a record has a venue needs also to have a date populated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think an issue is inside your **event_edit_view** function inside the views.py file, you should pass the formset in the context inside the POST method condition
do this in your else part instead of raising the validation error. It should work now.

```
def event_edit_view(request, id):
    .....
    if request.method == "POST":
         .....
    if MyOtherForm.is_valid() and form_date_event.is_valid():

        MyOtherForm.save()
        form_date_event.save()
        return redirect('my-events')

    else:
       context = {
           [other forms...]
           'form_date_event': form_date_event,
      }

      return render(request, "events/template.html", context)
```